# Using another test as test constructor

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I wonder how can I use one of my test case (test file also) (assume that tests are separated as one test for one file. I mean all js files includes only one test case).

It will be very good if I can use one of my test case(test file) inside fixture so that before a test starts it can prepare my environment with another test.

Suppose that my fixture is like below

```
import LoginPage from '../../../pages/login-page';    

fixture `Regression - UI`
    .page(DOMAIN)
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.maximizeWindow()
        await loginPage.login(t, EMAIL, PASSWORD);
    });
```

so what I want to do is execute another test after login is executed then run test *Adding a new item* test

```
test(`Adding a new creative`, async t => {

    await leftNavigation.clickCampaignSection(t)
    await leftNavigation.clickAllCampaigns(t)
}
```

so the fixture will gonna like below and EXECUTE.ANOTHER.TEST will gonna executed

```
import LoginPage from '../../../pages/login-page';
import EXECUTE.ANOTHER.TEST from ../another_test_file.js    

fixture `Regression - UI`
    .page(DOMAIN)
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.maximizeWindow()
        await loginPage.login(t, EMAIL, PASSWORD);
        await EXECUTE.ANOTHER.TEST
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not execute a test in other test or in one of a fixture hooks ([beforeEach](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/fixture/beforeeach.html), [afterEach](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/fixture/aftereach.html)). You need to create a separate method (`leftNavigation.addNewCreative`) with appropriate logic and call it when it's necessary.